# The continuity of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

$F$ is a function on $\mathbb R^n$ such that for every smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^n, \gamma(0)=0 $, we have $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to 0} F(\gamma (t)) = 0$, is it necessary that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left| x \right| \to 0} F(x) = 0$ ?

Comment: My intuition tells me that that is necessary. If there were a counterexample, you would build a series monotonically decreasing in absolute value $x_n \rightarrow 0$ such that either the limit doesn't exist, or isn't $0$. Either way you could build a smooth curve connecting the dots, and that would contradict the given. Although I haven't the time to formalise or even properly verify that thought.

Comment: @davin :My thought is the same, but when I construct a smooth curve outside $0$, I cannot guarantee this curve is smooth at $0$.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99078/can-continuity-of-a-function-be-checked-by-restricting-to-smooth-curves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question!

For $n=2$, you may find a positive answer to this question in *Remarks on the continuity of functions of two variables*, by Michael McAsey and Libin Mou. The proof is relatively difficult.

In the paper, the following theorem is proven:

> Let $D$ be an open subset of $\mathbf R^2$ containing $(0,0)$, and $f$
>   a real-valued function on $D$. If $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$,
>   then
>
> 1. There exists a continuously differentiable convex function $z \in C^1$ such that either $f(x,z(x))$ or $f(z(x),x)$ is discontinuous at
>      $x=0$;
> 2. For any integer $m\geq 0$, there exist functions $x(t), y(t) \in C^m$ such that $f(x(t),y(t))$ is discontinuous at $t=0$.

The authors state a similar theorem for $n=3$ (which also implies a positive answer to your question for $n=3$) and indicate how these results can be further generalized.