# Why are directional derivatives only defined with "line" vectors?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We have been shown that the existence of all directional derivatives doesn't imply the continuity of a function, since they only measure changes of the function when moving through straight lines.
When I asked why we can't use other types of curves, the answer was not clear at all. So, why can't we consider directional derivatives with arbitrary vectors? For example, $(x,x^2)$ for a function of two variables.

Comment: $(x,x^2)$ is not a vector, it's a vectorial function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$. If you are asking, *why can't we consider $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(0))}{t}$?* where $\gamma(t)$ is a curve that tends to the point at which we are studying the limit, the answer is that we can. Those are [limits along curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505321/limits-along-what-curves-suffice-to-guarantee-the-existence-of-a-limit).

Comment: Because the "directional derivative" you get from a differentiable curve is exactly the same as the directional derivative you get from the tangent line to the curve, provided the line is parametrized to go through the point at the same speed. Unless the curve is not differentiable, you get nothing new by using it instead of a line. You could use non-differentiable curves to examine certain pathologies in the function, but in general, such pathological curves hide the behavior of the function instead of illuminating it.

Comment: Wouldn't limits along curves only use the first term of the limit you wrote? That is, the lim as t goes to f(gamma(t))